# Leading flags in order

Tags: knowledge, visual, flags

**Complete the list by placing the correct flag in the empty rectangle below. Explain.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The missing flag is:

> [image: Flag of Ghana]
>
>  The flag of **Ghana**.

Why? Because these flags and the letters beside them represent:

> the nationalities and initials of people who have been the [UN Secretary-General](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary-General_of_the_United_Nations):
>
>  **T**rygve **L**ie (Norway)
>  **D**ag **H**ammarskjöld (Sweden)
>  **U** **T**hant (Myanmar)
>  **K**urt **W**aldheim (Austria)
>  **J**avier Pérez de **C**uéllar (Peru)
>  **B**outros Boutros-**G**hali (Egypt)
>  **Kofi Annan (Ghana)**
>  **B**an **K**i-moon (South Korea)
>  **A**ntónio **G**uterres (Portugal)
>
>  The missing person is the Ghanaian UN Secretary-General, **Kofi Annan**.

Note the hint in the title too:

> 'Leading' suggests leadership (and 'in order' helps us note that there is a sequence involved).

Comment: Well done! UNailed it ;)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Thant U very much!